# Microsoft Unit Test Feature - Determine if a test has been created for each public class/method?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, vs-unit-testing-framework

Is there anyway in VS2012 using Microsoft Unit Testing Framework (or TFS2012) to determine if a test has been created for each public method in a class?

I know the question is somewhat vague, but I want to know if there is a way to identify if a public method was added to a class whereby a test hasn't been created for it.

Comment: Are you looking for the Code Coverage tool? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537628.aspx

Comment: In a way yes ... I'd like to be able to identify a class and have an analysis done to tell me which public methods don't have any tests associated.